# AttributeError: module 'streamlit' has no attribute '_is_running_with_streamlit'. This attribute used to work properly but now it doesn't work anymore

Tags: python, streamlit

```
from streamlit.web import cli as stcli
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if st._is_running_with_streamlit:
        main()
    else:
        sys.argv = ["streamlit", "run", sys.argv[0]]
        sys.exit(stcli.main())
```

Above codes used to work without having any problem but now it doesn't work anymore when I **upgrade** my **streamlit** to **version 1.14.0**.

It will show the below problem when I try to run my program in the PyCharm IDE!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\juroy\PycharmProjects\TikTokAnalytics\app.py", line 66, in <module>
    if st._is_running_with_streamlit:
AttributeError: module 'streamlit' has no attribute '_is_running_with_streamlit'
```

What is the latest update for this?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution from the Streamlit community where I was actually using an internal API that Streamlit doesn't necessarily support. They wouldn’t recommend using this.

To replace that code so that it works, Streamlit suggests that I can use this:

```
from streamlit import runtime
runtime.exists()
```

So my code snippet from above needs to be modified to:

```
from streamlit.web import cli as stcli
from streamlit import runtime
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if runtime.exists():
        main()
    else:
        sys.argv = ["streamlit", "run", sys.argv[0]]
        sys.exit(stcli.main())
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the name of the file is not the same as the module you are importing – this will make Python think there is a circular dependency; most of the time this error and similar one will be gone by changing the name of the file.py if file name and module name are similar.