# AttributeError: module 'streamlit' has no attribute '_is_running_with_streamlit' when try using hiplot with streamlit

Tags: python, streamlit, hyperparameters

I want to display hiplot that is python package on streamlit locally. This is my code

```py
import streamlit as st
import hiplot as hip
import json

hiplot_data = [...] # raw data

xp = hip.Experiment.from_iterable(hiplot_data).display_st(key='hiplot')
ret_val = xp.to_streamlit(ret="selected_uids", key="hip").display()

st.markdown("hiplot returned " + json.dumps(ret_val))
```

This method I reference from this official hiplot website https://facebookresearch.github.io/hiplot/tuto_streamlit.html.
However, it not work at all. The error is `AttributeError: module 'streamlit' has no attribute '_is_running_with_streamlit'` I try to fix by add some line of code from this reference [AttributeError: module 'streamlit' has no attribute '_is_running_with_streamlit'. This attribute used to work properly but now it doesn't work anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74251573/attributeerror-module-streamlit-has-no-attribute-is-running-with-streamlit). So, the code will look like this

```py
import streamlit as st
import hiplot as hip
import json
from streamlit import runtime
runtime.exists()

hiplot_data = [...] # raw data

xp = hip.Experiment.from_iterable(hiplot_data).display_st(key='hiplot')
ret_val = xp.to_streamlit(ret="selected_uids", key="hip").display()

st.markdown("hiplot returned " + json.dumps(ret_val))
```

But it still show the same error.